# Does GatsbyJS StaticQuery fetch data at buildtime or at runtime?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I wasn't able to find a straightforward answer to this in the docs, and I worry that this might be an issue of me not understanding Gatsby/GraphQL data querying. Essentially I'm wondering whether GraphQL queries within your pages/components are running at build time or at client run time. For example:

Say I have a static website build with GatsbyJS and hosted on Netlify. On a page of the site, I make a query for an image hosted in the site server's filesystem. Something like this:

```
query {
  exampleImage: file(
    relativePath: {
      eq: "images/homepage/marquee_image.jpg"
    }
  ) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 400, quality: 90) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_withWebp
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Is this then going to run when the user visits the site to fetch the fetch the images and process it, or will it run the query and image processing at buildtime and make the data available to the client at runtime?

Comment: Your example query is extracted at buildtime. See https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/